# How to .count instances of current_level 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

I'm trying to `.count` on `current_level` when it's specifically at `6`. How should I write the method in **habit.rb**?

```
def current_level
        return 0 unless date_started
      def committed_wdays
        committed.map do |day|    
          Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES.index(day.titleize)
        end
      end

      def n_days
        ((date_started.to_date)..Date.today).count do |date| 
          committed_wdays.include? date.wday
        end - self.real_missed_days
      end     

  case n_days     
      when 0..9
        1
      when 10..24
        2
      when 25..44
        3
      when 45..69
        4
      when 70..99
        5
      else
        6 #how can we count all the habits that are on this level?
    end
end
```

I will then call that method in the application_controller so that I may use that method in the sidebar.

Please let me know if you need further code or explanation. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `Habit` is a model, inside `habit.rb`, and all habits in `Habit` belong to a single user, this should work for you :

```
class Habit < ActiveRecord::Base
  # other methods ...
  # Since it's a class method, you call Habit.best_habits.
  def self.best_habits_count
      all.count { |habit| habit.current_level == 6 }
  end
  # other methods ...
end
```

If they belong to different users, you need to add it in your `user.rb` , for instance :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # other methods ...    
  # call : user.best_habits_count
  def best_habits_count
    habits.count { |habit| habit.current_level == 6 }
  end
  # other methods ...
end
```

### Update

ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy has its own count method different from Array#count and it doesn't take a block. Because of that, the block given is ignored and it simple returns the number of records in the collection when called without any arguments.

More info here : [ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-count) on Ruby on Rails api.

So the solution simply is to use another way to count them.

### Final Solution

Put in **user.rb**:

```
  def count_mastered
    @res = habits.reduce(0) do |count, habit|
      habit.current_level == 6 ? count + 1 : count
    end
  end
```

Comment: I'm getting back "3", which is the total number of habits in my current_user's database right now, instead of "1" which is how many habits are at level 6. I can't figure out the problem with it. I tried `all.count { |habit| habit.current_level == n_days(6) }`

Comment: You should use count on the user's habits and not on the habits of `Habits.all`. Also are you sure that `current_level` of all the current habits does not return 6 ? (verify in rails console)

Comment: Updated to give an idea of how it would look like in a user model.

Comment: Yea regardless of if `current_level == n_days(6)` is `6`, `3`, or `30` it still shows `3` as the outcome. In the console it is saying for Level.find(x) `current_level: nil`

Comment: I put   `def best_habits_count
    @best_habits_count = current_user.habits.best_habits_count if current_user
  end` in the application_controller to call the method for the sidebar where I am showing it.

Comment: In the habit index `<%= habit.current_level %>` correctly calls out the right level number. habits `has_many :levels`

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com : The call in application_controller should be `current_user.best_habits_count` and not `current_user.habits.best_habits_count`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79236/discussion-between-limekin-and-anthonygalli-com).

Comment: Hey you're still up! I'm back in chat @limekin

Answer (score 1):

`.count` can take an argument which is the value you want to count. So, for instance, if you wanted had a list of habits and you called current_level on each one:

```
>> levels = habits.map(&:current_level)
=> [5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 6, 5, 4, 6]
```

And you wanted to count the number of `6`'s in the list, you could do this:

```
>> levels.count(6)
=> 2
```

Moreover, if you wanted to get the count for all of the levels:

```
>> Hash[*a.group_by(&:itself).flat_map{|k,v| [k, v.size]}]
=> {5=>2, 3=>1, 1=>3, 2=>1, 6=>2, 4=>1}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this:

1. `GET` all `habit`s of your `user`
2. Check if `habit`'s `current_level` == 6
3. Add it to a `counter` variable

If you really want to use the .count method :

1. `GET` all `habit`.`current_level` of your `user` and save it to an `array`
2. Use `.count` 6 to that array

Hope this puts you on the right path :)